# React Native App in iOS emulator forever stuck building

Tags: ios, macos, react-native

I've been following this intro course about React Native https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hf4MJH0jDb4 and when I get to the point to run the build it just gets stuck in "Building the app...." and never finishes.

I don't even get any error codes after running the command =>

`react-native run-ios`

It just gets stuck forever building with a large majority of my CPU being used. The  Xcode workspace is found, the iPhone emulator is launched and I can see the default screen, but the application just never finishes building.

Any insight on what could be causing this would be great—I haven't found anyone else with this specific problem.

> Operating System: macOS Big Sur Version 11.4

Answer (score 1):

I was just having the same problem with the difference that I use WebStorm and not Xcode, but it showed that it was actually really building. It took me approximately 15-20 minutes to build for the first time. The second time it took me something more than a minute.

Not sure why it took so long for the first time and I know that this is not technical advice, but try to give it a shot... I run it on an older laptop `MacBook 12" (2017), 8GB RAM, 1.2GHz Intel Core m3, Big Sur`.